# Unable to render more than one line using Rails and Prototype

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I'm having a really odd problem (which usually means I'm doing something wrong) with rails 3.0.5 and prototype. I'm using link_to to update a div:

```
*views/results/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "#{school[:name]}", {:controller => "results", :action => "update", :school => school}, :remote => true%>
```

This calls the controller function update:

```
*controllers/results_controller.rb
def update
  @selection = params[:school]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :action => 'index'}
    format.js
  end
end
```

Which renders update.js.erb ('selected' is a div in index.html.erb):

```
*views/results/update.js.erb
$("selected").update("<%= render :partial => '/results/academics', :locals => { :selection => @selection } %>")
```

**Here's where it gets strange.** If my partial academics.html.erb includes just one line of plain text, it works just fine. For example:

```
*views/results/academics.html.erb
<%= selection[:chances] %>
```

works fine. but if i have more than one line, it doesn't. For example:

```
*views/results/academics.html.erb
<%= selection[:chances] %>
<br>
```

Renders nothing. Server still responds with 200 OK, but div doesn't change.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[escape_javascript](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) is what you need

```
$("selected").update("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/results/academics', :locals => { :selection => @selection }) %>")
```